# Installation of gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu in ubuntu bionic on armhf cpu fails

Tags: linux, gcc, raspberry-pi3, armv7, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu and gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu under ubuntu 18.04, using the command

```
sudo apt install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

However I get this error message:

> Package gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> Package g++-aarch64-linux-gnu is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'g++-aarch64-linux-gnu' has no installation candidate E:
>   Package 'gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu' has no installation candidate

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains

> deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main universe deb
>   http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main universe deb
>   http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security main universe

I would be glad if somebody could help me with this (: